# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel even if it has properties

Tags: laravel

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    function one_one(){
        $data=Student::all();
        return view('welcome',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

In  View

```
@foreach($data as $std_marks)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$std_marks->std_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$std_marks->marks['java']}}</td>
        <td>{{$std_marks->marks['cprog']}}</td>
        <td>{{$std_marks->marks['csharp']}}</td>
        <td>{{$std_marks->marks['sqldb']}}</td> <--this is working 
        <td>{{$std_marks->marks->sqldb}}</td>   <--- here is the problem 
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

when i print `$std_marks->marks`  it display all the properties but when i print like above it showing exception

Comment: What is the type of `marks` column?

Comment: You are trying to access a variable from an array and not from an object.

Comment: use {{$std_marks->yourcolumn_name}} instead of  {{$std_marks->marks['java']}}

Comment: @Venkat can you post the `var_dump($data->marks)` ? As far as I think, this is not an issue at all. If the `marks` is an array you have to use `marks['index']` `marks->index` will only work if it is a collection or object.

Comment: Actually its marks has a relation with student it fetch the Prmary key of student and search in marks 
std_marks->data will retrive the object of marks table record